# Find a specific Google Document in Drive

Tags: file, google-apps-script, find, drive

I am trying to write a script to get the URL of a specific yet dynamic Google Document in Drive. The Google Document is created every Tuesday with its date at the end of the title of the Google Document.

"TypeError: Cannot find function getUrl in object FileIterator." error shows on line `var agendaURL = file.getUrl();`. Not sure how to debug this.

```
  var ssUrl = 'LINK BUFFERED';
  var sheetName = 'SHEET1';   // name of sheet to use
  var rangeName = 'C30';    // range of values to include 
  var dateRange = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssUrl)
                                .getSheetByName(sheetName)
                                .getRange(rangeName)
                                .getValues(); 


  // NEED TO find how to find file by name below!
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Weekly Agenda | " +dateRange);
  var agendaURL = file.getUrl();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you need to iterate through all of the files that meet the search criteria.  The solution is here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

```
   var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Weekly Agenda | " +dateRange);
     while (files.hasNext()) {
       var file = files.next();
       var agendaURL = file.getUrl();  
       return agendaURL //for first one, or you can return each one, push to an array, etc...
    }
```

Comment: utphx's answer worked for me.

As for K. Tanaike, the error came up for "files" since it is undefined.

Now, I realized there could be more than one file with the same name. How can I search in one specific folder in Drive where the file would be located in?

Comment: You can use getFolderById(id) found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String). If you run into trouble let me know and I help further

Comment: Excellent! This works now.

    `// Find Weekly Agenda of the week.
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID BUFFERED")
    var files = folder.getFilesByName("Weekly Agenda | " +dateRange);
    var file = files.next();
    var agendaURL = file.getUrl(); `

Answer (score 0):

The value which got by DriveApp.getFilesByName() is FileIterator. So it is necessary to retrieve the filename from the value as follows.

```
var filename = "Weekly Agenda | " + dateRange;
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
while (file.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  if (file.getName() == filename) {
    var agendaURL = file.getUrl();
  }
}
```